# SQLite. Сохранение информации о столбцах

Tags: sql, sqlite

Возможно ли в БД **SQLite** кроме самих данных сохранять пользовательскую мета информацию о столбцах?
Мне необходимо сохранять информацию следующего вида:
1. Текстовое описание столбца
2. Каким-то образом объединить часть столбцов в группу(например, добавив свойство, указывающее, что столбец относиться к некой группе)
Эта информация нужна для обработки таблиц одной программой. Например взять среднее от всех столбцов, входящих в группу итд.
**Пример.** Проводится тестирование прибора. На него подаются импульсы разной мощности(P) и частоты(F). Проводится ряд замеров, в каждом импульсы имеют свою мощность и частоту и вычисляется отн. погрешность точности измерения мощности(ke0). Таблица БД для результатов имеет следующие столбцы:
P,F,ke0
1дБ, 1кГц, 1.0
2дБ, 1кГц, 0.99
...
Мне нужно написать скрипт, который вычисляет среднее для измеряемого параметра(ke0). Я написал его
SELECT AVG(ke0) FROM Table;

БД изменилась, теперь в нее еще пишут отн. погрешность определения частоты(ke1).
P,F,ke0,ke1
1дБ, 1кГц, 1.0, 0.98
2дБ, 1кГц, 0.99, 0.97
...
Мне нужно чтобы прежний скрипт делал тоже самое(выводил среднее), но уже для 2-х измеряемых параметров - ke0 и ke1. 
Мой вопрос: можно ли создать универсальный скрипт, который будет работать и с БД типа 1 и с БД типа2 корректно?
Для чтения/записи/просмотра и всех операций с БД применяется sqlite3 и SQLiteStudio, для более сложной обработки ADO.NET и SQL запросы через библиотеку SQlite. Но возможно использование других(желательно бесплатных) приложений, если они лучше подходят для этой задачи.
Оба типа БД(как тип 1, так и тип 2) используются. Возможно будут новые типы БД, но создаваться будут по тому же принципу(например, добавят еще ke2 и k3)

Comment: Скорее всего вы пытаетесь решить вашу задачу каким-то неправильным способом. Что вам конечном итоге требуется сделать? Почему вы не можете просто создать таблицу `(имя_столбца, метаинформация, номер_группы)` например?

Comment: Требуется сделать БД с результатами измерений. Каждая запись таблицы - один замер. Одни столбцы хранят параметры, при которых производился замер, другие столбцы - измеренные параметры. Эти измеряемые параметры(их кол-во, тип, описание итд) будут меняться, а мне нужно написать генератор отчета унифицированный для любого кол-ва замеряемых параметров.

Comment: Другими словами, на входе:

Comment: Лучше сразу включайте эту информацию в вопрос. По сути по прежнему не вижу причин по которым нельзя эту информацию хранить в обычных таблицах. Приведите "минимальный пример" который вызывает у вас затруднения.

Comment: Ещё немного хотелось бы уточнить. У вас голый SQL или все такие есть какой-то клиент который пишет/читает в базу? И второе, БД типа 1 и 2 они просто разные встречаются или просто была база типа 1, а потом стала типа 2 (поменялась навсегда)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой скрипт написать можно (хотя за Sqlite на 100% я не поручусь всё же). Другое дело что его можно написать совсем разными способами. Например простой способ который я вижу. У вас где-то хранится список столбцов (в самой базе в отдельной таблице):

```
id | name
1  | "ke0"
2  | "ke1"
```

Перед запросом вы просто динамически строите SQL на базе этих данных. Из дополнительных плюсов таким образом можно включать/выключать столбцы в произвольном порядке. Аналогично в этой же таблице можно добавить `id` группы. Суть в том, что операцию построения динамического запроса *намного* проще реализовать на клиенте.

Можно немного потерять в потенциальной расширяемости, [используя](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) `PRAGMA database.table_info(table-name);` чтобы получать имена столбцов таблицы. Но суть при этом будет та же.

Comment: Легче иметь разные скрипты.

Comment: @Reffum не вижу каким образом легче. Если у вас поменялась база, то в случае скриптов нужно править сам скрипт, в случае описания - достаточно добавить данные.

Comment: Скрипт достаточно простой. Он считает среднее, Min, Max по каждому ke столбцу. Можно обойтись копипастой.

Comment: Я тогда не понимаю, если вас устраивает копипаста, то к чему ваш вопрос? Я так понял вам хотелось сделать дженеричное решение.

Comment: Мне хотелось сделать универсальный скрипт, но такой, который бы не вносил изменений в саму структуру БД. Не добавлял в нее новых, чисто служебных, столбцов.

Comment: @Reffum как я уже писал `PRAGMA database.table_info(table-name);` вернет вам имена столбцов. Так что на базе этих данных можно построить второй запрос.

Comment: Да мне, кроме имени столбца еще нужно краткое текстовое описание. И еще нужно столбцы, содержащие ke, объединить в группу. Ведь мне нужно среднее брать не от всех столбцов, а только от некоторых столбцов, и эти столбцы могут иметь произвольное имя.

Comment: @Reffum ну вот смотрите, эти ваши "краткое текстовое описание" и прочее не самозародится же? Кто-то должен будет это внести. Тогда я не вижу принципиальной разницы между содержанием этих данных в "самом столбце" и хранением в отдельной таблице. Так или иначе для поддержки этого нужен будет какой-то интерфейс.